# Browser displays site ip by default in javascript alertbox

Tags: php, javascript, iphone

Browser displays site ip by deafault in javascript alertbox.
When i m displaying alertbox in login page in iphone application,it displays site ip by default and validation is done through java script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true mostly when you are developping on your local machine, it shows your IP, when you deploy it, or use it on the web it will display the host name. So users will know exactly which website is displaying the alert box.It is by default in place of alert box's title position..

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers use the hostname (or ip address if there isn't one) that they are accessing the site though in the title of any alert messages. This is a security feature so that users know exactly which site is responsible for the message (which protects against phishing).

Obviously, it can't be changed as that would render it insecure.

Comment: The browser **has** to know the IP address of the site in order to request data from it. Anything the browser knows is known to the user. If you could stop the user from finding out the IP address, then you would stop them from accessing the website at all. No, you can't hide it, and there is no good reason to do so anyway.